# I need my Angular app to wait for the server to send the authentication cookie before canActivate() is called on the auth guard

Tags: angular, authentication, cookies, canactivate

I have an angular app, and authentication works, but when you open a new tab, the auth guard doesn't see the auth cookie(because the cookie hasn't arrived yet) and so the guard doesn't let you into the website. So I'm just trying to make multiple tabs work for my Angular app.

So the server sends a cookie(when it serves the app, I presume), that has your authentication ticket when you open a new tab.

However, when canActivate() is hit, this cookie has not arrived yet. It seems to arrive just a fraction of a second later.

Is there functionality for this in Angular? Or something to use besides canActivate()?

My current canActivate code:

```
canActivate(
route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

  // Get User cookie
  const userInfoCookieValue = this.findFirstInSource(
    document.cookie,
    'userInfo'
  );

  if (userInfoCookieValue) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

findFirstInSource(source: string, searchTarget: string): string {
  const pattern = '(?:(?:^|.*;\\...'; //cutoff regex for comment
  const expression = new RegExp(pattern);

  return source.replace(expression, '$1');
}
```

This always returns false, when opening a new tab and going to the website

Comment: A few remarks:
1) the problem also might be that the cookie is `httpOnly`
2) don't use it as a trigger to consider the app authenticated because you don't get a callback about it's presence
3) instead, use some network request's response as a trigger, store it in some service (or even in the state if you use such a thing) as an observable, and check that in the guard

Comment: Why would the cookie being httpOnly cause this behavior?

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies _A cookie with the HttpOnly attribute is inaccessible to the JavaScript `Document.cookie` API_

Comment: Ah right. No it is accessible, a moment after canActivate is called. It just doesn't exist yet when canActivate is called.

Do you happen to know when this cookie arrives? Is it just... served as part of the app, or maybe right after? I don't actually have access to the server code. It's a Spring Java app, so I assume it behaves however the default behavior is.

Comment: Then the next step would be to find out what call sets the cookie, using the browser dev tools.